# Indenting Table columns using Css and HTML

Tags: html, css

I have created a table using HTML , but the columns headers are just too close to each other and therefore i'd like to space them out using css.

in my HTML , I have created a table with headers like this:

```
<table class="DataTable">

        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>School</th>
                <th>First Namer</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Sport</th>
                <th>Enrollment Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>


    </table>
```

and in my Css file:

```
table.DataTable {

    border: 1px solid #79bbff;
//nothing much here , but how do I space out the headers?

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to add the following CSS rules:

```
table.DataTable th {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Adjust then the padding pixel size to your taste.

Answer (score 3):

If it's the text you're wanting to space out a bit, you can use `padding`:

```css
table.DataTable th {
    padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

A value of `4px 8px` will set the top and bottom padding to `4px` and the left and right padding to `8px`.

[image: Example]

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9jPke/1).

This is equivalent to using:

```css
table.DataTable th {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A [padding](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) is something you would need here.

http://jsfiddle.net/uuQ64/

```
th {
 padding:10px;
}
```

You can use this property to specify different padding for different sides.
Find more in that link.

Answer (score 0):

```
table.DataTable th {
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}
```

you can adjust the look and feel.